# Stack Overflow module for Drupal

Tags: discussion, addon

I've made a nice little [Drupal module for Stack Overflow](http://drupal.org/project/stackoverflow). Currently it enables display of the Stack Overflow.

The main advantage to just embedding the flair through JavaScript or iFrames is that this module uses Drupal's APIs for theming and caching, so it'll be faster and more performant, and in addition it should be a bit easier to set up instead of using custom blocks with raw code in them.

In the future I'll add the ability for each user to fill in his Stack Overflow/Server Fault/SuperUser ID and have his flair(s) show up on his user profile.

You can see the module in action and find more details in [my blog post about it](http://mikkel.hoegh.org/blog/2009/introducing-stack-overflow-module-drupal).

Bugs, suggestions, etc. should be posted in the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/stackoverflow).

Comment: Bleh, I can't edit my own post, since I'm considered to be a "new" user on Meta :(

Comment: Disassociate and then reassociate your accounts for the 100 rep points.

Comment: Voting to close as the drupal plugin is now several years old and is not being kept current - it doesn't use the new image based flairs, for instance.